# jQuery: Select all sub-elements which do not have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<li class="menu-has-children"><a href="#">Main</a>
<ul class="some-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Some Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="not-wanted"><a href="#">Some Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Some Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

And the following jQuery code until now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-has-children a', function(e) {
  $(this).nextAll('ul').eq(0).slideToggle();
});
```

My goal is to show all `li` elements of the next `ul` element after `this`, but exclude the li-elements, which have the `not-wanted` class attached. How could I achieve that?

I come so far to show ALL `ul` elements only as the above code implies, but I have no idea how to exclude the not wanted ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `not` function:

```
$('li').not('.not-wanted')
```

See [jQuery *not()* documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

For your case, it would probably look something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-has-children a', function(e) {
  $(this).nextAll('ul').find('li').not('.not-wanted').slideToggle();
});
```

This achieves the same results as using CSS3 `not` qualifier, but may be a bit easier to read. I can't vouch how it would compare in speed to the CSS3 `not` - this would need to be tested.

Comment: Best answer imho

Comment: Thanks Aleks, but what would be the full solution? Where should I exactly place your code? Append it to the `$(this).nextAll('ul').eq(0).slideToggle()` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 `not` selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-has-children a', function(e) {
  $(this).nextAll('ul').find("li:not(.not-wanted)").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. Does not show anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-has-children a', function(e) {
  $('li:not(.not-wanted)', $(this).next('ul')).slideToggle();
});
```

`:not()` selector will help you to exclude a set of elements out from the entire selection.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5g0hyfs/)

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. Does not show anything anymore

Comment: @chevallier Kind of messed up with the syntax. As I have touched UI elements a long back. You can check it now,.